# java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed: Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, stored-procedures, jax-rs

I am using helidon,for call stored procedure we use StoredProcedureQuery,to register we use
registerStoredProcedureParameter with parametername not index and for seting parameter we are using StoredProcedureQuery.setParameter but we are some time get sql error java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed: Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined.
Unaccepted effect on microservice:
i)After the issue arrised whole service crashed, no other operation are not allowed after this issue.

Please try to solve,its an emergency,I am totally stuck on the middle of a project.

Please find below code:-

StoredProcedureQuery query = this.entityManagerAdmin.createStoredProcedureQuery("USP_ENROLL_WIP_GET_SIGNUP_DET")
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_username", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_details", ResultSet.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

```
        System.out.println("setting parameter in query USP_ENROLL_WIP_GET_SIGNUP_DET");

        query.setParameter("p_username", username);

        System.out.println("Executing query USP_ENROLL_WIP_GET_SIGNUP_DET");
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)query.getOutputParameterValue("p_details");
```

If any any one even try to solve,success is not our hand.Advance Thanks to those people.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to debug into `org.hibernate.query.procedure.internal.ProcedureParameterImpl#canDoNameParameterBinding` to understand why it can't bind parameters via their name, but my guess is that your usage of `ResultSet` here is the issue. Hibernate is capable to map the result set into whatever you want if you provide a result set mapping, there is no need to process this yourself. Also see https://thorben-janssen.com/call-stored-procedures-jpa-part-2/#Stored_procedures_with_REF_CURSOR